# Having trouble with For Without Next Error with multiple variables in a VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am currently trying to arrange data that is in the same form in different sheets in a horizontal table. The sheets are labelled by Calender Week (CW6, C7 etc.) I also defined rows and columns as variables such that the query always jumps to the next field in the table.

Not sure if this works but I am currently stuck with this error

> For without Next

Here goes the code:

```vb
Sub Aggregate_Data()
    Dim cw_counter As Integer

    For cw_counter = Worksheets("VBA Update").Range("D6").Value To Worksheets("VBA Update").Range("D7").Value    
        Dim Column As Integer
        Dim Row As Integer

        For Column = 2 To 54
            For Row = 4 To 14
                Worksheets("VBA YTD Engage").Cells("Row,Column").Value = Worksheets("CW" & cw_counter).Range("Row,Column").Value
            Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that your code is properly indented, can you see it?

Comment: @Gass, I'm seeing three For loops with one next.

Answer (score -1):

### Copy Range from Different Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Aggregate_Data()
    
    Const crgAddress As String = "B4:BB14" ' Copy Range Address
    Const swsLeft As String = "CW" ' Source Worksheet Name Left
    Const dwsName As String = "VBA YTD Engage" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const uwsName As String = "VBA Update" ' Update Worksheet Name
    Const uwsMinAddress As String = "D6" ' Update Worksheet Min Address
    Const uwsMaxAddress As String = "D7" ' Update Worksheet Max Address
    Const Gap As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet Name Right Min and Max.
    Dim nMin As Long ' Update Min
    Dim nMax As Long ' Update Max
    With wb.Worksheets(uwsName)
        nMin = .Range(uwsMinAddress).Value
        nMax = .Range(uwsMaxAddress).Value
    End With
    
    ' Define Destination Range
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Worksheets(dwsName).Range(crgAddress)
    ' Clear contents below.
    drg.Resize(drg.Worksheet.Rows.Count - drg.Row + 1).ClearContents
    ' Determine Copy Range Rows Count.
    Dim crCount As Long: crCount = drg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Import data (ranges).
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim n As Long ' Source Worksheet Right Counter
    Dim wsCount As Long ' Source Worksheets Counter (for the MsgBox)
    For n = nMin To nMax
        ' Prevent error if worksheet does not exist.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set srg = wb.Worksheets(swsLeft & n).Range(crgAddress)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Copy.
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            drg.Value = srg.Value
            wsCount = wsCount + 1
            Set srg = Nothing
            Set drg = drg.Offset(crCount + Gap) ' Otherwise it's overwriting.
        End If
    Next n
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Copied data from " & wsCount & " worksheet(s).", _
        vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```